# Pasar datos mediante ajax y php a una tabla HTML

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, json

Intento llenar una **tabla** en `html` desde una consulta `ajax` y `php`.

**Problema:** Quiero obtener las dependencias de una tabla de `MySQL` (Solo tengo una agregada). Pero en php ingreso un array para que me lo devuelva en el ajax.

**clases.php**

```
<?php
if ($num_rows>=1) {
            //Se obtienen los resultados de la consulta
            while ($this->consulta->fetch()) {
                if($id_Estado == 1){
                    //Se guardan los datos en un arreglo
                $datos_json = array("Id_Dependencia"=>$id_dependencia ,"Nombre_Dependencia"=>$nombre_dependencia, "Id_Estado"=> $id_Estado, "Estado"=>"Activo");
                }else{
                    $datos_json = array("Id_Dependencia"=>$id_dependencia,"Nombre_Dependencia"=>$nombre_dependencia, "Id_Estado"=> $id_Estado, "Estado"=>"Inactivo");
                }
            }
            header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
            //Se devuelve el array pasado a JSON como objeto
            echo json_encode($datos_json, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);               
        }

?>
```

Al momento de recibir los datos en el `ajax` se hace correctamente, pero cuando quiero llenar algún campo de mi tabla tengo el siguiente problema:

> Como nota adicional estoy utilizando la funcion `.each` de `JQuery`.

**ajax.js**

```
function todasLasDependencias(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Funcion: 'Dependencias-todas'},
})
.done(function(data) {

    var tbHtml='';

    //Esta funcion recorre el array JSON devuelto por la consulta
    $.each(data.Nombre_Dependencia, function(index, val) {
        //Se asigna en una variable lo que sera nuestra tabla
        tbHtml +="<tr><th scope='row'>"+data.Nombre_Dependencia[index]+"</th></tr>";
    });

    $('#bodyTable-ND').append(tbHtml);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

El **resultado** es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Problema Caso #2:** Si hago unas modificaciones en el `script` donde tengo el ajax :

**Código modificado ajax.js**

```
function todasLasDependencias(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Funcion: 'Dependencias-todas'},
})
.done(function(data) {

    var tbHtml='';

    //Esta funcion recorre el array JSON devuelto por la consulta
    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        //Se asigna en una variable lo que sera nuestra tabla
        tbHtml +="<tr><th scope='row'>"+data.Nombre_Dependencia[index]+"</th></tr>";
    });

    $('#bodyTable-ND').append(tbHtml);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

> Modifiqué los parametros de la funcion **`.each()`** agregando solamente `data`.

Yo solo quiero obtener los datos sin que se cuatripliquen.

El **resultado es el siguiente**: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La estructura del `objeto json` es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muestra con que estructura queda el resultado de la consulta, al llegar al `JavaScript` (data) por que de eso depende como debas recorrerlo para usarlo.

Comment: @Michael Eso de la estructura,¿Qué vendría a ser?, ¿La estructura del array?

Comment: Imprima en la consola la variable `data` que recibe en `.done` y mire el formato, por que desde `PHP` lo esta enviando como una cadena `(JSON.encode)`. En ese caso debería de usar `JSON.parse` para pasarla a `object` en `JS` (recuerde que con `.each` no se puede recorrer un `object`). y debería de cambiar su `th`(este solo se usa para la cabecera de la tabla) por `td`(este para el cuerpo de la tabla)

Comment: @Michael acabo de editar y poner una imagen de la consola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que esta recorriendo mal el `object` pruebe así:

```js
/*este seri el object ejemplo*/
var data = {
  Estado: "activo",
  Id_Dependencia: 1,
  Id_Estado: 1,
  Nombre_Dependencia: "Sistemas"
}

/*crea la variable y abre el <tr>*/
var tbHtml = '<tr>';

/*recorre el object y agrega a tbHtml los <td>*/
for (var dato in data){
  tbHtml += '<td>' + data[dato] + '</td>'
}

/*cierra el <tr>*/
tbHtml += '</tr>';

/*agrega tbHtml al DOM*/
$('table tbody').html(tbHtml);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Dependencia</th>
      <th>Estado</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Así no le quedaria en orden con la tabla, lo que debe de hacer seria ordenar esto:

`$datos_json = 
 array(
    "Id_Dependencia"=>$id_dependencia,
    "Nombre_Dependencia"=>$nombre_dependencia, 
    "Id_Estado"=> $id_Estado, 
    "Estado"=>"Inactivo"
 );`

En el mismo orden de la tabla, o viceversa.

Comment: Y si solamente quisiera los nombre? como podria ser

Comment: @FernyCortez que nombres?

Comment: @Solo el nombre de las dependencias, osea no imprimir todos los datos del array

Comment: en ese caso ya no debería recorrerlo, si no agregar uno a uno, para que pueda seleccionar cuales si y cuales no. `<td>data['estado']</td><td>data['Id_Estado']</td>`....

Answer (score 1):

Lo que falla es la parte de javaScript, tu código no es correcto, te lo adjunto modificado:

```
function todasLasDependencias(){
$.ajax({
    url: '../../php/instancias.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {Funcion: 'Dependencias-todas'},
})
.done(function(data) {

    var tbHtml='';

    //Esta funcion recorre el array JSON devuelto por la consulta
    let indice = 1;
    for(aux in data){
       //Esto se corresponde a cada fila de la tabla
       tbHtml +=`<tr>
                     <th scope='row'>${indice++}</th>
                     <th scope='row'>${aux["Estado"]}</th>
                     <th scope='row'>${aux["Nombre_Dependencia"]}</th>
                 </tr>`;
    }

    $('#bodyTable-ND').append(tbHtml);
})
.fail(function() {
    console.log("error");
});
}
```

Un saludo.